# Static electricity—electron donor/acceptor

Tags: homework-and-exercises

At school, we were taught that in a situation where one material gets rubbed with another, there's a transfer of electrons. This is because the electrons (or charges) jump from one material to the other due to friction.

And we were also told that one of the materials tends to be the giving one in the exchange, which we call the electron donor. And the electron acceptor is the one that takes in the electrons offered by the corresponding electron donor.

And we were given a table with examples of electron donors and acceptors along with that, of the classic hair/comb sort.

When our teacher helpfully added that whether a material acts as an electron donor or acceptor depends on the material it is being rubbed with, it got me thinking.

I was wondering if there were certain pairs of electron donor/acceptor. Pairs of specific materials that synchronise with each other. In the sense that one material in the pair exhibits either of these behaviours only in case of the other material in the pair.

Say, you’ve got material X which you rub with material Y. It acts as a electron donor perhaps. But it doesn’t always behave like an electron donor. You see that it acts as an electron donor only upon friction with that specific material Y.

Do such pairs exist? Hope I had been able to express my question clearly enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate: (or at least I think it provides an answer): https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/103457/question-on-static-electricity-electron-transfer

Comment: @StudyStudyStudy Nope, that question is in no way related to what I'm asking here.

Comment: Hi, in your question you are, in effect, asking for a list imo;), "Pairs of specific materials that synchronise with each other." but i don't think that is on topic here. Whether the answer I cited is actually  a duplicate or not, I think it gives an explanation, which is more on topic for here (although a list might be found on Chemistry.StackExchange).

Comment: @StudyStudyStudy Ah, god, I'm not asking for specific examples of pairs. I'm asking whether they even exist in the first place. Our teacher hadn't made it clear that electron donor/acceptors work in pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your teacher has mentioned the triboelectric series, which basically lists various materials according to their tendency to accept or donate electrons. Here is a [link](https://www.school-for-champions.com/science/static_materials.htm#.W6e_A-j25PY) to one of many pages on this topic.

If you take two materials at the opposite side of this series, the outcome would be predictable. If the materials are close to each other - not so much, i.e., the outcome could be affected by the state of their surfaces or other factors and, in general, the effect won't be significant.

I have not heard of anomalies, though, where two materials on the opposite sides of the triboelectric series, would switch their personalities when paired together.

Comment: Does that mean you can only create electricity if you have an electron donor and an acceptor? Is it impossible to create static electricity if, say, two electron donors are used?

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine Sure it is possible - the division to donors and acceptors is just a matter of convenience (many versions of triboelectric series tables do not make this distinction). It is just that, when two materials are close to each other in the serires, it is hard to predict which way the exchange will go or if it will happen at all.